# ApplicationWindow doesn't respect size

Tags: ios, qt, size, qml, qtquick2

I'm having an issue understanding the `width` and the `height` attributes of the `ApplicationWindow` setting in a very simple IOS program. Take for instance the following code:

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Window 2.2
import QtQuick.Dialogs 1.2
import QtQuick.Layouts 1.1

ApplicationWindow {
    title: "Hellow"
    width: 1024
    height: 1920
    visible: true

    Rectangle{
        width: 300
        height: 300
        color: "blue"
    }
}
```

When I compile using Qt 5.5 my blue `Rectangle` appears much larger than I would expect. I've played with the `width` and `height` of the `Rectangle` and it seems like the `ApplicationWindow` is more on the order of `width: 390`, `height: 650` regardless of what I have set.

Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: Probably your target platform display resolution is lower than what you want.

Comment: A screenshot might help. I didn't know that specifying the size of the window had any effect on iOS; on Android it does nothing, as the application will always be full-screen.

Comment: I guess what I thought the ApplicationWindow size was (on IOS devices) was a canvas size more or less. Then when I use rectangle coordiantes like 100x100 and I say my canvas size is 500x500 the recentangle would be only 1/5 the size. Perhaps this is not how I should look at this.

Answer (score 0):

The [High DPI Displays](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/highdpi.html) documentation might be useful here. In particular, you could try setting `QT_DEVICE_PIXEL_RATIO` to `1` before running your application and see if that results in the `Rectangle` being sized in the way you want it to be.

Comment: I'm not sure how I would set an environment variable on an iphone before starting the application..

Answer (score 0):

This link answers my question.

https://forum.qt.io/topic/43513/solved-ios-retina/6

Specifically from there:

> On iOS the dimension that you get is the logical dimension of the iOS
>   screens. This happens also if you program natively with Xcode on iOS.
>   So, when you create a Rectangle of 320 logical pixel, on non-Retina
>   iOS devices it will use 302 real pixel, but on retina iOS devices it
>   will use the double of pixel (640).

The link also offers some additional advice on how to get screen independent drawing.